# Typing effect with blinking caret Pure CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to implement a typing effect for multi lines using only pure CSS, but I am having some difficulties.
1) The blinking caret doesn't stop right after the words have been typed. It just continues on until the end of the div.
2) How to remove the first blinking caret after it finished?

```css
  .typing h1 {
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            letter-spacing: 0.5em;
            border-right: 1px solid orange;
            animation: typing 4s steps(40, end), blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite;
        }

        .typing h1:nth-child(2) {
            opacity: 0;
            animation: typing2 4s steps(40, end), blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite;
            animation-delay: 4.5s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @keyframes typing {
            from {
                width: 0;
            }
            to {
                width: 100%
            }
        }

        @keyframes typing2 {
            from {
                width: 0;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            to {
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        /* The typewriter cursor effect */

        @keyframes blink-caret {
            from,
            to {
                border-color: transparent;
            }
            50% {
                border-color: orange;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="typing">
        <h1>First Line</h1>
        <h1>Second Line</h1>
    </div>
```